# how to end ng serve or firebase serve

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli, firebase-tools

I've been doing web development with Angular2 and have been using both Angular2 and Firebase to run local servers. I haven't been able to find a command similar to typing quit when using Ionic to create a server, so I have to close the terminal tab each time. Is there a way to end the server and get my terminal tab back?

Thanks.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

You can use the following command to end an ongoing process:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: I have ng serve running in a console window, and it just is not responding to ctrl+c at all.

Comment: In case of using IntelliJ, pay attention to open the first console u used, ng is still running there, you might have multiple console tabs opened

Comment: @ShawndeWet: same here, on Windows 10 with angular 10.x.x; however, it seems to take a minute or 2 to respond. Pressed CTRL+C and 2 minutes later I had the "abort batch process (y/N)" prompt. Edit: pressing ctrl+c multiple times doesn't seem to reduce this time.

Answer (score 41):

I was able to stop via this on Windows for Angular 8:

Step 1: Find 4200 process

```
netstat -ano | findstr :4200
```

Step 2: Kill that process:

```
taskkill /PID <PID> /F
```

[image]

Comment: Seems unnecessarily hard when you can use Ctrl+C ?

Comment: @Caltor when you close that terminal but the server is running it is very much helpful in that scenario

Comment: @Caltor in my case Ctrl+C in the console was just giving me ^C which is totally useless.

Comment: Did the job for me on Windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: only works on cmd, doesn't run with Bash

Answer (score 39):

Try using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> twice to get the prompt for terminating the batch job.

Comment: Ctrl+c twice needed

Comment: @Jonathan Please make sure you fix as much as possible when you suggest an edit. In this case make sure the sentence starts with a capital letter and ends with a point for example.

Comment: Actually the first time shows the prompt `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` and it looks like the second time forces the termination.

Answer (score 38):

If you cannot see the "ng serve" command running, then you can do the following on Mac OSX (This should work on any Linux and Uni software as well).

```
ps -ef | grep "ng serve"
```

From this, find out the PID of the process and then kill it with the following command.

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Comment: Thanks you that helped me. If you are on Windows, just open the task manager and kill the node.exe process. Hope this will help

Comment: taskkill /F /IM node.exe (Careful: this force closes all instances of node.exe on Windows)

Comment: thanks for this. this is what i needed since my app was still running even after shutting down webstorm

Answer (score 24):

If <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> doesn't work use this:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>c</kbd>

Sometimes people change the behaviour of ctrl + c for copy/pasting so you may need this.

Of course, you should also ensure that the terminal window has keyboard focus, ctrl + c won't work if your browser window has focus.

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>   **OR**
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>

Both will ask for Terminate batch job, 
then press Y or y and click enter.

Comment: [ctrl] + [Pause/Break] did it for me on Powershell 7/Windows 10, too!

Answer (score 5):

for stop angular project press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> **twice** , then press <kbd>Y</kbd> , then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Can use

```
killall -9
```

The killall command can be used to send a signal to a particular process by using its name. It means if you have five versions of the same program running, the killall command will kill all five.

Or you can use

```
pgrep "ng serve"
```

which will find the process id of ng and then you can use following command.

```
kill -9 <process_id>
```

Comment: I like this and you can shorten it even more with the following: ``kill -9 `pgrep "ng serve"` ``

Answer (score 2):

With Windows 10 / Powershell <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> did not work;
Powershell tried to gracefully stop the app.

Used normal cmd and had no issues stopping the **ng serve** with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

it is enough to modify something in your text editor and reload localhost. 
all your connection will be lost nd you have opsibility to ng serve the new project in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run this from within the Visual Studio 2017 Package Manager Console. None of the above suggestions worked.

See [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/69881/package-manager-ng-build-doesnt-stop.html) where Microsoft states "The solution is not to use package manager for angular development, but instead use powershell command line. ".

Answer (score -2):

----Ctrl + c then choose Y from the Y/N option provided.

Comment: This answer duplicates existing answers and adds nothing new. In fact is also lacks better formatting present in other previous answers.

Answer (score -2):

Exit the IDE and boots up IDE again , try it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow you can check the link [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) so your answers will help more people

Comment: Only relevant if you are running ng serve inside the IDE terminal

Answer (score -3):

On macOS Mojave 10.14.4, you can also try <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> in a terminal.

Comment: that kills terminal, not ng serve command