# How to close a server created in WebStorm, "ng serve"

Tags: webstorm

I had a class involving WebStorm last semester and today I tried to access my final project, in which I type `ng serve` into a terminal window to start a server, then copy/paste an HTTP: link into my browser.

The problem is, I don't remember how to stop the server from running. I'm sure it's another command I type in the terminal, I just cant remember or find it online.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39080622/783119 ??

Comment: pressing `Ctrl+C` in terminal normally terminates the running process

Comment: You could also kill the running process in whatever process monitor your OS has (Task Manager, Activity Monitor, etc...). Lena's advice is best, though.