# Unable to kill 'ng serve' in GitBash

Tags: angular, command-line, git-bash, taskkill

I am using GitBash terminal and running an Angular application through local development server using `ng serve`. When I want to stop running the server, I try methods such as `ctrl + c` and even `taskkill /pid 14892 /f`, but nothing happens. It carries on running and the only way I can stop it is by closing GitBash and then killing the process through command line. I have a looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39074678/how-to-end-ng-serve-or-firebase-serve#:~:text=Try%20using%20ctrl%20%2B%20c%20twice,for%20terminating%20the%20batch%20job.), but nothing works

**Question**

How do I kill `ng serve` and carry on using the GitBash terminal?

Comment: Try using ctrl + c twice.

Comment: What OS are you using, I've tried replicating it on Windows ctrl + c works fine

Comment: Windows 10. I don't know if it may be my configuration files that are causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing it that way too. The only way that worked for me is that I killed Node.js JavaScript Runtime through task manager and it ended the Angular process.

Comment: Before posting an Answer,  ensure that your answer is the exact solution of the question. If you are not unsure about your post, then you should post your solution as a comment, not the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).